# How to fetch the data from the different tables in android?

Tags: android, string, sqlite, cursor

My application has multiple SQLite tables(around 20 with different fields). This I have created it using Adapter class(Here i have just mentioned one class Game, Like that i have 20).

```
public class MyDbAdapter {
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private static MyDatabaseManager mDbManager;
Context ctx;

public MyDbAdapter(Context context) {
       this.ctx =   context;
    mDbManager = new MyDatabaseManager(context);
    mDb = mDbManager.getWritableDatabase();
}

public static final class GameColumns implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE = "game";
    public static final String IMEI = "imei";
    public static final String LAST_UPDATE = "lastupdate";
    public static final String NICKNAME = "nickname";
}



private static class MyDatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbname";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 8;

    private MyDatabaseManager(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        createGameTable(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

       db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+GameColumns.TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void dropDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + GameColumns.TABLE);
    }

    private void createGameTable(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + GameColumns.TABLE + " ("
                + GameColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + GameColumns.IMEI + " TEXT,"
                + GameColumns.LAST_UPDATE + " TEXT,"
                + GameColumns.NICKNAME + " TEXT);");

      }
  }
 }
```

Data From each table is fetching using below code. This function returns Cursor object.

```
public Cursor getRecords(String tableName){
    Cursor cursor   = mDb.query(tableName, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    return  cursor;
}
```

I need to convert Cursor Object to either list or string. For this we need to iterate the cursor Object. My problem is, each table has different fields, So i need to iterate each cursor object in separate method. How can this be done using single method?
Is there any direct way to convert cursor to string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `HashMap` like...

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

int col_count = cursor.getColumnCount();
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        HashMap<String, String> currentItem = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < col_count; i++)

                        {
                            String col_name = cursor.getColumnName(i);
                            currentItem.put(col_name, cursor.getString(i));
                        }
                        items.add(currentItem);
                    }
                    cursor.close();
```

Comment: Same way, How can we insert using single method?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `String` array containing table column names as an argument to your `getRecords()` method. Then just iterate over the `Cursor` fetching the values for each column. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
ArrayList<Object> attayList;

if(tableName.equals(table1)){
arrayList=new ArrayList<Table1ClassType>();
}
if(tableName.equals(table2){
arrayList = new ArrayList<Table2ClassType>();
}
```

the main moto is creating new instance based on data, so you may check the table type & create new instance, then use `arrayList` easily.